# Missing data in differential item functioning analysis

Tags: missing-data, psychometrics

I'm currently analyzing items from a bank for K-12 education. I have a separate data set for each grade/subject combination (for example, 1st grade English is a set, 2nd grade English is a set, etc). Each data set contains 400-7000(!) items.

I would love to able to run various DIF analyses, but missing data is a huge problem. Each student in the data set has answered only a fraction of the items. For example, in the 1st grade English data set, I have an N of 4000, but no one student has answered more than 50 percent of the 400 items, and the percentages of missing answers is above 90 percent. This is actually one of the more complete data sets I have. I expect the set with 7000 items to have a percentage missing in the 95 or above range.

My questions: there's absolutely no way to perform Mantel-Haenszel, IRT-based, or any other form of DIF on data with so many missings, right? Even if my program of choice (STATA) returned results (which it doesn't), that this information would be unreliable, invalid, and otherwise useless?

Also, assuming the above is the case, any suggestions for things I might try to measure different function by groups in lieu of conventional DIF, even if it's not particularly sophisticated?

Thanks in advance,

Bryan

Answer (score 1):

@Bryan: I agree that the missing data will create a problem with classical test theory.  Both IRT and Rasch are quite robust to missing data however (the size of the measurement error just increases with missing data).  As long as you peform DIF within a Rasch or IRT framework you should be able to demonstrate DIF across class groups, sex, etc.  A search of the [Rasch Measurement Transactions](http://www.rasch.org/rmt/contents.htm) website should help you find suitable references.

Comment: This is way outside my expertise, but with so much missing data, don't you have to be very careful of (self-)selection effects in responses?

Comment: Absolutely, even with Rasch (the simplest model) the missing data will impact the confidence with which the item parameters can be estimated.  Sample sizes with Rasch do not have to be as high as for 2- or 3-parameter IRT models.  As long as there are 100 or more responses for each item (in each subgroup being compared), some cautious comparisions can be made.  It is wise to not over interpret the results.